# Pythonic way of getting max of dictionary after applying custom function

Tags: python, numpy

I have a python dictionary with numpy arrays as values. I need to iterate through all keys and apply a custom function to each value. The function returns a float64 number. Then I need to get the key of the element which returned the maximum value (after applying the function)

This is my code so far, but I think there should be a pythonic way to do it:

```
 max = -999
 match = 0
 for c in Centroids.keys():
   corr = Functions.Correlation_fast(tmp, Centroids[c])
   if corr > max:
      max = corr
      match = c
```

In this case **match** will have the key of the dictionary with the greatest value.

There must be a better way to achieve the same, what do you think?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`max`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#max):

```
max(Centroids, key=lambda x: Functions.Correlation_fast(tmp, Centroids[x]))
```

Comment: Yep, I get the following error: TypeError: 'numpy.float64' object is not callable

Comment: This should work just fine. Did you drop the `lambda`?

Comment: @MartijnPieters: The OP is using NumPy arrays, but `Centroids` is a dict, and `Correlation_fast` returns a float64. Without refactoring `Centroids` to not be a dict, this is probably about as good as it gets.

Comment: @user2357112: Check, noted.

Comment: Should I add some kind of casting? I keep getting the above error

Comment: @JorgeZapata Don't forget to use the `lambda` with the key argument.

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary sorry, I'm new to lamba functions, I've read very little about them and your code should work but I think the error is beacuse max built-in method doesn't support numpy.float64 ndtype, isn't it?

Comment: @JorgeZapata `lambda` is just an inline form of the def based based function(but has some limitations), and `max` works fine with NumPy scalars as well. Please post some sample data and actual code that can reproduce the error.

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary sorry I had a problem and was out of town, your code works great now, I was using "max" as variable in some part of my code and python got confused. Thanks for your neat code =)